# How to know whether an AWS Elastic Load Balancer is used?

Tags: amazon-elb

I have an active ELB in my AWS account as well as EC2, VPC, RDS etc.
I'm trying to understand whether this ELB is used or connected to something before deleting it.

Any idea of what should I look for?
The ELB belong to a VPC, has 3 availability zones and a security group apparently created by Elastic Beanstalk (probably an early experiment).

There are no instances ID.

There is a listener, http on port 80.

In monitoring, I see everything empty except the 4 Estimated ALB counts (connection count, consumed LCUS, newconnectionCount, processed Bytes)

If possible, I would like  to understand if other things in my account are using it, before deleting it.

Maybe an alternative to deleting it, just "disabling" it in some way would also be useful. I'm not sure I can recreate if something goes wrong.

Comment: Are the connection counts and processed bytes non-zero?

Comment: You could disable it by blocking access to it via its security group rules.

Comment: @ceejayoz Requests Count=0, Estimated ALB Active&New Connection Count >0, Estimated Processed Bytes>0

Answer (score 1):

If there are no instances registered with it, then it is sitting idle doing nothing, even if requests are coming to it. Regardless, check Route53 to ensure that there are no records pointing to it (or other DNS provider; although, the IPs associated with the ELB may have changed), AutoScaling to ensure that a group does not launch into it, and CloudFormation to ensure a template does not require it.

If requests are coming in, and no instances are registered, you will see HTTP_5XX errors in the CloudWatch metrics. You can enable access logs on the ELB to see where the requests are coming from (this would be helpful even if instances are registered).